# Getting RSA private key with .NET Core

Tags: c#, rsa, x509certificate2, cng

On .NET Core (3.1), on both Windows and Linux platforms, I want to decrypt a message using the private keys of X509Certificiate2 instances. The certificates are retreived from certificate store on Windows platform, and from PFX file on Linux platforms respectively.

I wish to decrypt the message using something like:

```
static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, RSAParameters privateKey)
{
    using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
    {
        rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
        return rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    }
}
```

But when I try to extract the private key, I the an exception: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported."

```
var privateKey = x509cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var privateKeyParams = privateKey.ExportParameters(true); // <-- throws CryptographicException
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get the exception on Windows only or on both?

Comment: The error occurs at least on windows platform. Will test on Linux soon.

Comment: The error was also on Linux. @Crypt32 fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signaure of your own `Decrypt` method to accept an instance of `RSA` class in the second parameter. You are doing some extra job by exporting private key into plaintext form and then import it to another object just to decrypt.

```
var privateKey = x509cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
```

this line already returns an instance of `RSA` class. That is, all your code is simplified to:

```
using (var rsa = x509cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    return rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
}
```

The exception is thrown because your private key is not exportable. And you don't really need to have exportable key.

Comment: Perfect - didn't need the KeyParameters at all. Thanks a lot!